# NHibernate - ICriteria for two tables?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm having a heck of a time creating the ICriteria for two tables.
The SQL I am trying to mimic is below.
Is there anyway to do this? 
I've been trying CreateAlias, Subqueries, and a bunch of other stuff But I always end up with errors.
I have tried posting this on the nhusers Google group, but not getting much help.
Thanks.

### Kim

```
SELECT *
FROM Echo_File_status efs, Data_DELETION_PARAMETER ddp 
WHERE 
   efs.EFS_PRODUCT_CODE = DDP.DDP_PRODUCT_CODE(+) 
AND 
   DDP.DDP_PROCESS_TYPE = 'D' 
AND 
   ( ( trunc(nvl(efs.efs_file_create_date, sysdate)) > sysdate - dp.DDP_DAYS_ON_LINE ) or 
   ( efs.efs_status_code != 'ACKED' ) ) 
ORDER BY efs.efs_product_code, decode(efs.efs_status_code, 'READY', 1, 'TRANS', 2 , 'FAERR', 3, 'FCERR', 4, 'PRERR', 5, 'TRERR', 6, 'PREP', 7, 'PRCOM', 8, 'FCREA', 9 , 'TRCOM', 10, 'ACKED', 11, 1), 
      efs.efs_file_create_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use icriteria while Hql would be easy to use? Join the objects on that code property.

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion on this kind of problem, is that you should just keep writing expressions like that in pure SQL, since it will only be worse to read and maintain using the NHibernate criteria API.

As long as you have test coverage on the query, you can safely hide that implementation detail away.